# Mapped Vuex function "is not a function", but still loads

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

When I call a mapped Vuex action in my mounted hook, the action works, but I get "TypeError: xxx is not a function" error in the console.

Here's my whole script section for this component:

```js
<script>
import SideNav from '@/components/SideNav.vue'
import ActionBar from '@/components/ActionBar.vue'
import Summaries from '@/components/Summaries.vue'
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: { SideNav, ActionBar, Summaries },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['dataLoading']),
    ...mapActions(['init'])
  }, 
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I believe the issue is because the life cycle of vue calls the `mounted()` function before the properties are computed. place the `...mapActions(['init'])` in your methods instead and see what happens.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should map Actions as `methods` instead of `computed`, see [dispatch actions in components](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components):

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['dataLoading'])
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['init'])
},
mounted() {
  this.init();
}
```